# File.WriteAllText() statement in C# not creating a file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, save, savefiledialog

I am still only just learning C# in Visual Studio and I am trying to make a simple text encryption application. My problem at the moment is that when I use the command:

```
File.WriteAllText(name, inputTextBox.Text);
```

(Where name is the name of the file chosen in a SaveFileDialog and inputTextBox.Text is the text in a textbox on the main form)
however the file is never actually created. I even tried to build the application and run it as administrator but nothing happened.

What's even weirder is when I opened File Explorer, in the Quick Access section where it shows recent files, all the files that were supposed to be created show up there but don't exist when I click "Open File Location" and if I just try to open them, notepad just tells me the file doesn't exist.

The files are also not in my recycle bin or anything.
Here's the rest of my code in case it's something wrong with that:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = saveDialog.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(name, inputTextBox.Text);
    }
```

And in case you're wondering saveDialog is already an element in my form so there's no problem with that.

Comment: Did you register the event handler `saveDialog_FileOk`?

Comment: when you set a breakpoint inside `saveDialog_FileOk` does it halt? and what does it tell you about the `name`?

Comment: @Mong No, it isn't even registering the FileOk event.

Comment: @TacoMakerMan it doesn't halt even though you have registered the event ?=! could you post the code of where and how you registered it?

Comment: @MongZhu I'm not exactly sure what you mean but I added it by just typing it in from a tutorial, but using the name of my SaveFileDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your posted code the initialization of the `SaveFileDialog` is missing, and you say in your comment that the Debugger doesn't halt in the event body I take the long shot to assume that the event is not registered appropriately.

Try to make sure that your class (minimally) looks like the following example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    SaveFileDialog saveDialog;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // create instance of SaveFileDialog
        saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        // registration of the event
        saveDialog.FileOk += SaveDialog_FileOk;
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveDialog.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = saveDialog.FileName;
        File.WriteAllText(name, inputTextBox.Text);
    }
}
```

If your problem still remains, then I will remove my answer

Comment: I deleted my "saveDialog_FileOk" private void and added it by double clicking the event on my actual form and that seemed to work. It turns out it was a lot more simple than I thought, but thanks :)

Comment: sometimes it is :)